# Loading a page after progress bar loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a progress bar that loads from a width of 1 to 100 percent with javascript. Just wanted to find out if there is a way to mess with the javascript to make it load a page after it reaches a width of one hundred percent. Here is my javascript for that.

```js
var i = 0;

function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("mybar");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
        elem.style.delay = "3s";

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "Load a page?"

Comment: open a new page?

Answer (score 1):

Set the window.location.href property inside the "if (width >= 100)" part

```js
var i = 0;

function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("mybar");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
        setTimeout(function () {window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'}, 3000);
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
        elem.style.delay = "3s";

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay am gonna try that, Thanks for the help, will sure reach out to you if the code doesn't work

Comment: It didnt work, it loads the page directly without first making sure that the progress bar reaches a hundred percent

Comment: :/ It shouldn't execute that line until it enters in that if. What are the css styles of mybar?

Comment: Yeah thats what's bugging me too but i did exactly as he told me.

Comment: I've edited the answer, I didn't see that you are putting a delay of 3s in the style of the bar. If you put that delay, then the change of page has to have the same delay too.